# MySQL conditional UPDATE using IN

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

I have a database table with a column named *featured* which is used to highlight featured content on a page. Currently, I'm using two SQL statements to toggle the featured rows on/off like so:

```
-- Reset everything to non-featured
UPDATE tbl SET featured = '0'; 

-- Now set the selected rows as featured.
UPDATE tbl SET featured = '1' WHERE id IN (4, 10, 21);
```

Is it possible to combine both of these into one statement?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use:

```
UPDATE tbl SET featured = id IN (4, 10, 21);
```

**[EDIT]**

@OMG Ponies:

that works, you can take advantage of the fact that boolean conditions in Mysql can be directly mapped to integer.

in Postgresql, you have to do this, need to cast the boolean to integer:

```
update tbl set featured = (id in ('b','d'))::int
```

Comment: Cool.  The OP has the numbers within single quotes, just have to cast/convert if it's necessary.

Comment: indeed, the auto-conversion would be a performance hit if you didn't explicitly cast/convert

Answer (score 7):

Use:

```
UPDATE tbl
   SET featured = CASE 
                    WHEN id IN (4, 10, 21) THEN '1'
                    ELSE '0'
                  END;
```

Answer (score -3):

Yes, you can combine both of these into one statement.

Comment: While that may literally answer the question asked, I don't believe this is a helpful response. The implied question is "how can a single statement be constructed to do this?"

Comment: @jigs: Nobody likes a smart alec.

Comment: UPDATE Activity SET Activity.Charges = 10
WHERE (Activity.[Activity ID]) In (2,3,4);

This is a example which is working.

Comment: @ddc0660: maybe jigs have acquired bad habits from becoming a programmer heheh :D http://stackoverflow.com/questions/164432/what-real-life-bad-habits-has-programming-given-you/164446#164446